# How can I add Levels to my game with less duplication of code?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, code-duplication

I am designing a game with multiple levels. I have a setup class that sets up the board based on the argument it receives, which indicates which level it should set up. Here is the class:

```
public class BoardState {
    public BoardState(InitialState state) {
        switch (state) {
            case EMPTY:
                setupEmptyState();
                break;
            case INTEGRATIONTEST:
                setupIntegrationTestState();
                break;
            case LEVEL_1:
                setupLevelOne();
                break;
            case LEVEL_2:
                setupLevelTwo();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error("Invalid level selection");
        }
    }

    private void setupEmptyState() { }

    private void setupIntegrationTestState() { }

    private void setupLevelOne() { }

    private void setupLevelTwo() { }
}
```

This works fine, but every time I add a new level I have to add code in three places: The `InitialState` `enum` which defines the list of accepted states, the `switch` statement in the constructor, and the body of the class, where I have to add a method to set up the level in question.

One nice thing that I want to keep is the fact that my GUI automatically populates with a new button for each level I add based on the `enum` defining the list of levels.

**How can I refactor this code so that there is less overhead associated with adding a new level?**

Comment: This is a very wide question indeed. There is no specific answer there. It depends on how much your level setups have in common. We do not know the nature of your game, if it is designed to have finite number of levels then this is your best way then you really need to see what is common between those levels and make a method for it and call it on initialization. If it is designed for infinite levels then your whole code needs recreation

Comment: How similiar all the `setupX()` methods are ? Can you post their code ?

Comment: @Spotted quite similar - they just involve adding objects to a linked list. the created objects vary in number and position based on the level.

Comment: I have edited my answer with more thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when you need to reduce code duplication, an interface arise. This time (based on your comment in OP) it seems you need to add different objects to the board depending on which level you are:

```
import java.util.List;

public interface LevelSettings {
    List<GameObject> startingObjects();
}
```

Now, `BoardState` looks like that (no more `setupX()` methods)

```
import java.util.List;

public class BoardState {
    private final List<GameObject> gameObjects;

    public BoardState(LevelSettings settings) {
        this.gameObjects = settings.startingObjects();
    }
}
```

Since you also specified it is nice for you to have an `enum` to dynamically creates buttons on the GUI, one can combine the best of both world (interface and enum) by implementing the interface in an enum...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public enum InitialState implements LevelSettings {
    EMPTY {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    },
    INTEGRATIONTEST {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            GameObject g1 = new GameObject("dummy 1");
            GameObject g2 = new GameObject("dummy 2");
            return Arrays.asList(g1, g2);
        }
    },
    LEVEL_1 {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            //read a config file to get the starting objects informations
            //or also hardcoded (not preferred)
        }
    },
    LEVEL_2 {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            //read a config file to get the starting objects
            //or also hardcoded (not preferred)
        }
    };
}
```

And that's it basically. If you need to add `LEVEL_3` do it in `InitialState` and everything will follow.

## Going one step further

From here it goes beyond what you requested, feel free to ignore this part if you are not convinced.

As a good practice I would store these configurations only in config files to reduce even more the code duplication and gain in flexibility:

```
import java.util.List;

public enum InitialState implements LevelSettings {
    EMPTY {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            return readFromFile("empty.level");
        }
    },
    INTEGRATIONTEST {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            return readFromFile("integration_test.level");
        }
    },
    LEVEL_1 {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            return readFromFile("1.level");
        }
    },
    LEVEL_2 {
        @Override
        public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
            return readFromFile("2.level");
        }
    };

    private static List<GameObject> readFromFile(String filename) {
        //Open file
        //Serialize its content in GameObjects
        //return them as a list
    }
}
```

So that when you decide to add a new level you actually only need to know the filename in which the level's configuration is stored.

## Going another step further

**What you will see there is really tricky and I don't advice you to use it in production code** (but it reduces code duplication) !

```
import java.util.List;

public enum InitialState implements LevelSettings {
    EMPTY, INTEGRATIONTEST, LEVEL_1, LEVEL_2;

    @Override
    public List<GameObject> startingObjects() {
        return readFromFile(this.name() + ".level");
    }

    private static List<GameObject> readFromFile(String filename) {
        //Open file
        //Serialize its content in GameObjects
        //return them as a list
    }
}
```

Here we rely on enum names themselves to find the corresponding correct file. This code works because it is based on the **convention** that the files are named accordingly to the enum names with the ".level" extension. When you need to add a new level, just add it to the enum and that's it...

Comment: This does everything I want. I will play around with the details, but I will definitely be implementing something similar to this in my game. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use inheritance, **polymorphism** is the keyword here.

Set up your `InitialState` class as abstract base class (or interface if you have no common fields) and define a method `public abstract void setup();`.

```
abstract class InitialState {
    public abstract void setup();
}
```

Then, for each of your original switch cases, derive a class from your base class, for example `LevelOne`, and implement its specific by overriding `setup()`.

```
class LevelOne extends InitialState {
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        // The code from "setupLevelOne()" goes here
    }
}
```

Your `BoardState` class reduces to this:

```
public class BoardState {
    public BoardState(InitialState state) {
        // At runtime, the right method of the actual
        // state type will be called dynamically
        state.setup();
    }
}
```

However, if you need to set interal state of your `BoardState` class, consider defining the setup method as `public abstract void setup(BoardState boardState)`, so you can access its getter and setter methods.

This appraoch could also foster reuse of code, as you could add several abstract layers for different types of levels.

Comment: I suspect most of the setup involves private state on `BoardState`.

Comment: Not a bad answer overall, but it does have one problem - by using an `Enum` to list the board states I have the GUI set up to automatically populate a button for each level. If I change to your solution, I will still have to edit code in many places for each new level: I will need to add a new button for each implementation of `InitialState`, define that button to create the correct implementation, and I will need to write the `setup()` method of each implementation. If there were a way to dynamically create a button for each implementation of `InitialState`, this would be perfect.

Comment: @nhouser9 Hey that's a new requirement there, that you didn't specified in the OP ! Consider updating it please.

Answer (score 1):

well you can refactor all of the work into a one method.
say it takes an int as the ID of the level, while it loads a JSON file containing structured information of each level, and creates the given level.
for example :

```
"levels" : [
  "level" : {
      "id" : "001",
      "size" : "200",
      "difficulty" : "2"
  },
  "level" : {
      "id" : "002",
      "size" : "300",
      "difficulty" : "3"
  }
]
```

then, in your code:

```
public void setupLevel(int id) throws levelNotFoundException{
    //somehow like this
    Document doc = parse("levels.json");
    for(element elm: doc.get("levels")){
        if(Integer.parseInt(elm.get("id")).equals(id)){
            //setup your level
        }
    }
}
```

and then somewhere you call your method:

```
int levelId = getNextLevel();
try{
setupLevel(levelId);
} catch (LevelNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

or you can use XML, or simply hard code it, and store all levels in an array